# Finding values or objects in a json file with nested objects and passing the result object to child in Javascript and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am working on a react project where I am dealing with a json file of the following format.

```
{
   "trees":{
      "name":"a",
      "age":"9",
      "height":"10",
      "location":"park"
   },
   "cars":{
      "name":"b",
      "age":"30",
      "height":"10",
      "location":"park"
   },
   "bikes":{
      "name":"c",
      "age":"110",
      "height":"10",
      "location":"park"
   },.........................
```

The data from the json file (name , age, height , location) is shown in a table in a child component but now I am working on a functionality such that on whatsoever row of the table is clicked that rows data is shown in another component.

I am handling it such that whenever a row is clicked a function sends the name(eg. a or b or c) to the `App.js` and what I want to do is that find that values(name,age,height,location) corresponding to that name , store it and send those values to another child.

I am not able to traverse through this json file to find that values corresponding to the name and also dont have an idea how to store these multiple values to send it to a child.

This is what I tried to find the values(name , age , height , location) corresponding to the name:

```
const selected = Object.entries(Data).find(([key, { ...e }]) => {
  key.name === selectedId;
});
console.log(selected + "Selected");
```

and I am getting error.

Comment: How?   I am able to send data from the json to different components without any error. I am having trouble in finding data in this json.

Comment: the problem is the `{}` with no return statement. But I think you've over complicated this with the destructuring. It is as simple as this: `const selected = Object.entries(data).find(a =>a[1].name === selectedId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
const obj = {
  "trees":{
     "name":"a",
     "age":"9",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "cars":{
     "name":"b",
     "age":"30",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "bikes":{
     "name":"c",
     "age":"110",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  }
};
const selected = Object.values(obj).find(e => e.name === 'c');
```

Or try like this:

```
function findByName(obj, name) {
  const selected = Object.entries(tmp).find(([_, e]) => e.name === 'c');
  const [key, findObj] = selected;
    return {
      [key]: findObj
    }
}
console.log(findByName(tmp, 'c'));
```

Comment: That ignores the object type (trees, cars, bikes).